# Рекурсивный перебор словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть словарь в котором хранятся данные вида

```
tree = {'Записи': {'Новая запись ': {'Новая запись 2': {}, 'Запись уровень 2': {}}, 'Запись - Уровень': {}, 'тест': {}, 'Новая запись 2-0': {}}}
```

Подскажите, как написать рекурсивную функцию, что бы такой словарь разобрать в массив вида

```
array = ['Записи', 'Новая запись ',  'Новая запись 2', 'Запись уровень 2', 'Запись - Уровень', 'тест', 'Новая запись 2-0']
```

Причем сложенность словаря может быть любой. Уверен, что такой вопрос уже задавался, но я что то не могу придумать рекурсивный метод для такого. Спасибо всем, кто подскажет!

Comment: нужно забрать только ключи?

Answer (score 5):

```
tree = {'a': {'b': {'c': {}, 'd': {}}, 'e': {}, 'f': {}, 'g': {}}}

def deep_keys(obj, arr = None):
    if not arr: arr = [] # Список создается один раз, при первом вызове.

    for key, val in obj.items():
        arr.append(key)

        if type(val) == dict:
            deep_keys(val, arr) # Передается на заполнение в дальнейшие вызовы...

    return arr

print( deep_keys(tree) ) # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

* При передаче списка в виде аргумента функции, копируется не сам список, а ссылка на него. Работая со ссылкой на один и тот же объект `arr`, все вложенные вызовы напрямую добавляют туда элементы через `arr.append(key)`.